# Change matplotlib y-axis limits to required power format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got following plot: 
[image]

Presently I have 1e-1 as common base for all y-ticks. I want to change it to 1e-2. 
My present code:

```
plt.plot(xact,[i-j for i,j in zip(yact,iv_i)],'o') # type(xact) type(iv_i)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html

Comment: `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(-2,-2))`

Comment: @JohanC Yes! It worked. Thanks.